# Can we reuse one environment build files into another build without doing npm run build in angular

Tags: angular, npm

I have used more than 3 environments in angular. Is it possible to reuse of one environment built files into remaining environments without doing build. If it possible means how can we do it. I need configuration setup for it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use the build files because those files are already in a build state with minification and compression with the environment you sepecify . You have the buld again with the environment you want.

Comment: Oh ok, is there any option to reduce build time? If we can't use build files means how can we reduce time for build. For single build taken 20 to 30minutes.

Comment: it does not take that much of time for a single build. There must be problem with ur machine or code base. It takes maximum 5mins for the build. Use command ng build --prod --aot

Comment: For me, it is asking to increase size when build. How can we do "ng build with node --max_old_space_size=4096".

Comment: I used below scripts in package.json:
"scripts": {    
    "build": "node --max_old_space_size=4096 ./node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/ng build",
 "appStart": "npm run build -- --c demo && npm run build -- --c demo1 && npm run build -- --c demo3"
  }

Comment: if you have installed the angular-cli globally you can just use ng build --prod --aot to build your app. It will give you buils application in the dist folder. That is the most covenient way

Comment: when i use ng build --prod --aot this, my build asking to increase size. How can i use ng build --prod --aot with size??